# react-router: Switch Redirect not working in localhost:xxxx. Redirect from baseUrl to some other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have to configure routing for my app. I am doing it on my local system.
The packages that I am using are `"react-router": "^4.3.1"`, `"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"`, `"history": "^4.7.2"` and `"connected-react-router": "^4.3.0"`.

I want user to be redirected to `http://localhost:xxxx/login`, when he navigates to `http://localhost:xxxx`. In real case scenario on prod, the `baseUrl` shoul be picked from `window.location.pathname` and then user should be redirected to login.

It doesn't solve the purpose in the code below. On entering `http://localhost:3000` a new path name `http://localhost:3000/login` is visible in the url bar, but the login page does not load. All I see is a blank page.

In the code below, however, if I `return /` in History.js and remove second route from Routes.js, the login page loads successfully.

History.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';                          

function checkUrl() {                                                              
  let baseUrl = window.location.pathname;                                          
  window.localStorage.setItem('baseUrl', baseUrl);                                 
  return `${baseUrl}`                                                              
}                                                                                  

const history = createHistory({                                                    
  basename: checkUrl(),                                                            
});                                                                                

export default history;
```

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';                                                         
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';                              
import Login from '../Pages/Login/Login';

const Routes = () => (                                                             
  <Switch>                                                                         
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />                                
    <Route
       exact                                                                        
       path="/"                                                                     
       render={() => (
         <Redirect to="/login" />
       )}
    /> 
  </Switch>
);

export default Routes;
```

Store

```
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import history from '../history/history';

const routeMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history); 
//I have applied the middleware and configured rest of the store, here only exposed relevant information that I am using `connected-react-router`
```

I came across many articles to solve this, tried many P&C. But I am unable to wrap my head around this.

Comment: check your login Component if something (like redux) is not blocking an update. Also you can try to switch the routes order and put "/" route as first. I'm using it in a similar way and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started to function correctly once I wrapped my App.js in `withRouter`.

Answer (score 1):

It’s most likely that your updates are being blocked. See: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration
The jest of it is to wrap your export of connected component in ‘withRouter’ so that the route props are being added, triggering a re-render due to prop differences

Quoting the link cited above:

“Generally, React Router and Redux work just fine together. Occasionally though, an app can have a component that doesn’t update when the location changes (child routes or active nav links don’t update).

This happens if:

The component is connected to redux via connect()(Comp).
The component is not a “route component”, meaning it is not rendered like so: 
The problem is that Redux implements shouldComponentUpdate and there’s no indication that anything has changed if it isn’t receiving props from the router. This is straightforward to fix. Find where you connect your component and wrap it in withRouter.”

Comment: My Login component is a stateless component.

Comment: That doesn’t matter if the component is connected with redux store. It has props, and evaluates a diff, try it and see if it works.

Comment: I tried `export default withRouter(connect(null, null)(Login))` and `export default withRouter(Login)`. Still the same issue.

Comment: The latter part of your post, you mention a blank screen and if you remove the second route you get login screen.. This means it’s failing to match your route, and switch is falling back to only route. Could you try to omit the exact keyword from the login route

Comment: Apologies, I was under the impression you were using redux due to using connected-router. It seems like your code you want to go to login page regardless. If that’s the case make it the only route with no path in switch statement. Otherwise I would redirect from base route inside the base component if ! LoggedIn to home with a <Redirect/> component

Comment: Removing exact from Login Route too doesn't solve the issue. In only one case where I change `return ${baseUrl}` to`return /` in History.js and then directly hit `localhost:3000/login` am I able to see the login page.